# Generation of square wave using Veilog

Tags: verilog

Am just messed with the generation of a square wave of specific frequency and a duty cycle using Verilog and dumping to FPGA kit.  Can anyone clarify how the clock frequency is derived?? Which bit is to selected while using the derived clock frequency??
 Here is an example code for generating square wave of 1KHz with 50% duty cycle.What modifications need to be done to generate a square wave of frequency 2KHZ and 40% duty cycle in the present code??

```
module square_wave(clk,rst,dac_out);
  input clk;
  input rst;
  output reg [0:7] dac_out;
  reg [7:0] temp;
  reg [7:0] counter;

  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    temp <= temp + 1'b1;
  end

  always @(posedge temp[3])
  begin
    if (rst)
      begin
        counter <=0;
      end
    else
      counter<=counter + 1'b1;
  end

  always @*
  begin
  if (counter<=127)
    dac_out=8'd1;
  else
    dac_out=8'd0;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: What is the frequency of the input `clk`?

Comment: Well it's 4MHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 4 MHz input `clk` and a 1 kHz output clock `dac_out`, we need a counter which counts

$$n=\frac{f_{in}}{f_{out}} = \frac{4\,MHz}{1\,kHz} = 4000$$

cycles of the input clk and then wraps to zero, i.e. it counts from 0 to \$n-1\$ . This defines the period of the output clock. A duty cycle of 50% (x%) is defined by setting the output to high for the first

$$m = \frac{x\%}{100\%}\cdot n = \frac{50\%}{100\%}\cdot 4000 = 2000$$

cycles, and low for the rest of the period.

I have improved your code for a better understanding:

```
module square_wave(clk,rst,dac_out);
   input clk; // assuming 1 MHz
   input rst;
   output reg dac_out;
   reg [11:0]  counter; // 12-bit for numbers up to 3999

   always @(posedge clk)
     begin
        if (rst == 1'b1  ||  counter == 12'd3999) // period, count from 0 to n-1
          counter <= 0;
        else
          counter <= counter + 1'b1;

        // synchronous output without glitches
        if (rst == 1'b0  &&  counter < 12'd2000) // duty cycle, m cycles high
          dac_out = 1'b1;
        else
          dac_out = 1'b0;
      end
endmodule // square_wave
```

By changing the marked counter checks, you can adjust the period and the duty cycle of the output clock.
For example, a period of \$n=2000\$ cycles and duty cycle with \$m=800\$ gives the required output clock.